# Is there a solution to invoice delivered qty ?

Tags: odoo, invoice, stock

I would like to know if there a solution to invoice just the delivered qty ( delivered qty - returned qty) in odoo
or I must code it ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

inherit **_get_invoice_line_vals** of stock_move in the module *stock_account*

```
def _get_invoice_line_vals(
     ...
     #search for (deliverd - returnedQty)
     qty = 0
     quant_obj = self.pool.get("stock.quant")
     uom_obj = self.pool.get('product.uom')
     quant_search = quant_obj.search(cr, uid, [('history_ids', 'in', move.id), ('qty', '>', 0.0), ('location_id', 'child_of', move.location_dest_id.id)], context=context)
     for quant in quant_obj.browse(cr, uid, quant_search, context=context):
         if not quant.reservation_id or quant.reservation_id.origin_returned_move_id.id != move.id:
             qty += quant.qty
     qty = uom_obj._compute_qty(cr, uid, move.product_id.uom_id.id, qty, move.product_uom.id)
     quantity = qty
#         quantity = move.product_uom_qty
     # set UoS if it's a sale and the picking doesn't have one
     uos_id = move.product_uom.id
#         if move.product_uos:
#             uos_id = move.product_uos.id
#             quantity = move.product_uos_qty
#             
    ...
```

Answer (score 1):

As I know there is no any option to invoice delivered qty.
You have to code for that option.